# How to highlight drastically edited question?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I've posted a question yesterday, with fairly few information about the problem (the information I had at that time was posted), and today I've edited it and provided a lot more information (basically from the research I've did in the problem).

But now, my question doesn't appear in any list on Stack Overflow, because basically it is a question from yesterday. How could I draw more attention to my question after I've made a lot of improvements to it? I would be willing to offer a bounty if someone is able to solve my problem, but I still have to wait a day until I am eligible to offer a bounty.

Comment: Based on what it says there, there is no real way(even after a large redo of a question, even after providing a lot more useful information) to get more attention to a question that is already posted. Do I have the right to repost my question then, so it appears once again on the front of the respective tag lists?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Do not repost the question. When you edited the question, it was bumped up in the list of active questions.

Comment: Um, no. But you need to be patient instead. Stack Overflow is not waiting for you, it's the other way around. The >100K Top User that can tell you exactly what is wrong may be asleep or at work. Possibly both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Also, questions get bumped to the "active" tab when edited. Do _not_ make meaningless edits just to bump your post, but it would be helpful to document your research in the post as you wait some time to post a bounty.